# R Splitting a dataframe into multiple dataframes and do calculation on it, and replace the calculated value while keeping everything else iteratively

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, indexing

I have a data frame with 15 rows shown below.

`(iris[1:50, c(1,2)])`

The data can be seen as

| SN | Sepal.length | Sepal.width |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5.2 | 3.5 |
| 2 | 4.9 | 3 |
| 3 | 4.7 | 3.2 |
| 4 | 4.6 | 3.1 |
| 5 | 5 | 3.1 |
| 6 | 5.4 | 3.6 |
| 7 | 4.6 | 3.9 |
| 8 | 5 | 3.4 |
| 10 | 4.4 | 2.9 |
| 11 | 4.9 | 3.1 |
| 12 | 5.4 | 3.7 |
| 13 | 4.8 | 3.4 |
| 14 | 4.8 | 3 |
| 15 | 4.3 | 3 |

I want to take do calculations on every three rows of Sepal.width starting from row no. 5 until 12 iteratively and return the values in multiple dataframes. For example, I will increase the values of selected rows by 10%, such that I will get the following dataframes.

First dataframe (value changed of row 5,6,7)

| SN | Sepal.length | Sepal.width |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5.2 | 3.5 |
| 2 | 4.9 | 3 |
| 3 | 4.7 | 3.2 |
| 4 | 4.6 | 3.1 |
| 5 | 5 | 3.41 (changed value) |
| 6 | 5.4 | 3.96 (changed value) |
| 7 | 4.6 | 4.29 (changed value) |
| 8 | 5 | 3.4 |
| 10 | 4.4 | 2.9 |
| 11 | 4.9 | 3.1 |
| 12 | 5.4 | 3.7 |
| 13 | 4.8 | 3.4 |
| 14 | 4.8 | 3 |
| 15 | 4.3 | 3 |

Second dataframe (value changed of row 6,7,8)

| SN | Sepal.length | Sepal.width |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5.2 | 3.5 |
| 2 | 4.9 | 3 |
| 3 | 4.7 | 3.2 |
| 4 | 4.6 | 3.1 |
| 5 | 5 | 3.1 |
| 6 | 5.4 | 3.96 (changed value) |
| 7 | 4.6 | 4.29 (changed value) |
| 8 | 5 | 3.74 (changed value) |
| 10 | 4.4 | 2.9 |
| 11 | 4.9 | 3.1 |
| 12 | 5.4 | 3.7 |
| 13 | 4.8 | 3.4 |
| 14 | 4.8 | 3 |
| 15 | 4.3 | 3 |

And So on until the value of row 10,11,12 is changed.

So far I have done as below:

```
window<- slide(seq_len(nrow(iris)), .f = ~ .x, .after = 2) %>%
keep(~ length(.x) == 3) %>%
map(~  iris %>% 
      slice(.x))
value<- lapply(window,change1)
```

Here, `change1` is a separate function that does the calculation on the multiple dataframes from `window` i.e increases the value of selected rows by 10%.

So far the code only works on the entire data frame that is row 1 to 15, and not on just rows 5 to 12, and I am also unable to replace the changed value while keeping all the original values intact as described in the example.

I am working on time-series data I need to do calculations only in the second column with the data (i.e. Sepal.width for now)

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the trick?

```
map2(list(5:7, 6:8,10:12), rep(list(df),3), function(x,y) { 
  y[x , 2] = y[x , 2] * 1.1
  
  return(y)
  })
```

this solution is very scalable, just change up some numbers

```
map2(seq(1,nrow(df) -3 ,3), seq(3, nrow(df),3), function(x,y) {
  
  ndf <- df
  ndf[x:y, ] = ndf[x:y, ] * 100
  
  return(ndf)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I have a data frame with more than 10000 rows of data, and the calculation is little more than just increasing by 10%. The data was just an example of how it would look in the final solution. Here I would have to specify the data frame manually, which would be cumbersome for a lot of data.

Comment: You said 10% so I can only go with what you said. It's easy to adjust the percentage though. My example is scalable, all you would have to do is change the numbers slightly and it would work on any data.frame of any length

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I wasn't able to clarify. The main part I needed help with was creating the data frame. I was just using 10% as an example on the data. I was hoping to use a function to do the manipulation, and return the modified data frame.

Comment: My example creates a list of data.frames, you said you wanted to create multiple data.frames and apply a multiplication to it. That's what my example does, it creates as many data.frames as you would like.